# Splash screen text changes color

Tags: c#, splash-screen, textcolor

I currently have a text box on the bottom portion of my splash screen that displays the last build date. The text color is set to black but for some reason when you run the splash screen the color starts out at black, turns to white and then turns back to black right before the actual program starts. This is only happening on Vista. Does anyone know why this would happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help Chandra! I managed to fix it finally by switching the transparency color of the background from black to white. I have no idea why it worked but it did so I figured I would post it on here so if someone else has this obscure (and annoying) problem they can check that.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and that was because of multiple panels having different backgrounds over each other. See if setting the form's doublebuffered = true helps.